# How to point a triangle at the tip of a line [R]

Tags: r, plot

I am using a triangle to mark an event on a timeline in R, and I've given the coordinates to the specific position on the line where the event occurs in days. In the `points(` function, I have supplied `pch=25` to create the "filled triangle" shape. However, the positioning of the character is based on the center of the triangle. Is it possible to use an argument like "pos" (i.e. pos=3) so that the triangle is positioned immediately above the line and points to to X coordinate of interest?

Example:

```
plot.new()
segments(0, 0.5, 1, 0.5)
points(0.5, 0.5, pch=25)
```

have

[image]

want

[image]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick It seemed straightforward to me, but anyway I added the code/have/want.

Comment: I don't believe such a feature exists for plotting characters. I don't think they are aware of their own size. You could just bump the position a bit `points(0.5, 0.52, pch=25)` or plot your own triangles with `polygon` and have complete control over vertex positioning.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is an inherent function for this (i.e. `pos`-like function) but in the past, I have added a manual adjustment:

```
plot.new()

adj <- 0.015

segments(0, 0.5, 1, 0.5)
points(0.5, 0.5 + adj, pch=25)
```

[image]

So with multiple points:

```
points(seq(0.1, 0.9, 0.1), rep(0.5, 9) + adj, pch = 25)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since R's interpreter supports a wide variety of encodings, and since the `pch` is just the text input, you can just paste the down triangle into the text editor and calculate:

`strheight('▽') -> l`

and change the last line to
`points(0.5, 0.5 + l/2, pch=25)`
to get the desired

[image]

```
> strheight('▽')
[1] 0.1022132
```